# fflib service layer naming convention

Tags: fflib, naming-convention

I read an article about the service layer [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_sl_principles). The names for the services are OpportunitiesService.cls or AccountsService.cls. Does the names of the services always follow the pattern {plural Sobject}{Service}.cls? What are the best practices? I would like to create services with the following naming OpportunitiesCreator.cls or AccountsCreator.cls? is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Andrew Fawcett, page 163 *Salesforce Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture*

> The actual name of the service can be pretty much anything you like, typically a major module or a significant object in your application. Make sure it is something from your application's vocabulary. If you've structured your application design well, your service class names should roughly fall into the groupings of your application's modules...

In our org, we have `AccountsService`, `OrdersService`, etc corresponding to major objects (Account, Order, ...)  We also have services that don't directly correspond to a single SObject such as a `SObjectFieldHistoriesService` that deals with operations on field history records.

Be careful not to create services that are really methods. in your example, you might want something like an `ActorsService` with methods such as `create(SObjectType sobjType)` but I'm just speculating without more understanding of your use case.

Reference that fflib was based on: [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) by the inestimable Martin Fowler

Comment: Thanks, @cropredy, without you my code writing would be a pain.